# Enforce repository interfaces to have certain methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository:

Dog:

```
public interface DogRepository extends JpaRepository<Dog, Long> {

    @Query("select d from Dog d where ?1 MEMBER OF d.owners")
    List<Dog> findAllForUser(String user);

    @Query("select d from Dog d where ?1 MEMBER OF d.owners and d.id = ?2")
    Dog findOneForUser(String user, Long id);
}
```

I want a RestrictedRepository which enforces the creation of findAllForUser and findOneForUser:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface RestrictedRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{
    List<T> findAllForUser(String user)
    T findOneForUser(String user, Long id);
}
```

and I want the Dog repository to extend this instead of JpaRepository. However every time I do this I get an exception of:

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOneForUser found for type Dog!

Removing the findOneForUser method from the RestrictedRepository resolves this issue and my findAllForUser works as expected.

Full code example available at https://github.com/imduffy15/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa the code causing the exception is commented out.

What is causing these exceptions and how do I fix or workaround it?

Comment: If you explicitly looking by entity id, put it first in WHERE query, although RDBS optimizer should do it for you. Have you tried to do this with Query features of JPARepository (by simply declaring findByIdAndOwnersName() & findByOwnersName() in your Repository) (Just curious:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer for this from @thought_forge on twitter.

By moving to:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Dog.findOneForUser", query="select d from Dog d where ?1 MEMBER OF d.owners and d.id = ?2")
```

On the domain resource rather than on the repository the exception goes away and the application executes as expected.

Possibly a bug with @Query.

I will update the linked github example accordingly.